# Is there any XmlIgnoreAttribute or equalvent in java technology

Tags: java, xml, performance, xml-serialization

The above are the points taken from this site 
http://blog.ibeesolutions.com/web-services-implementation-considerations.html

Serialization is an important issue from the web services’ performance point of view since web services uses XML in SOAP messages.

So  Reduce Serialization with `XmlIgnore`

To limit which fields exposed by an object are serialized when the object is passed to or from a Web method and to reduce the amount of data sent over the wire, the `XmlIgnore` attribute should be used as shown below.

The `XmlSerializer` class ignores any field annotated with this attribute.

Please note that `XmlIgnore` serializes only public members unlike the formatters derived from `IFormatter` interface.

```
// This is the class that will be serialized.
public class MyClass
{
// The str1 value will be serialized.
public string str1;

/* This field will be ignored when serialized–
unless it’s overridden. */
[XmlIgnoreAttribute]
public string str2;
}
```

Here the author mentions about the tips on Inproving Webservices and on of them is to use XmlIgnoreAttribute

I have developed a Webservice using Java through  Apache CXF Framework .

Please tell me how can I use that or any similar attribute with in Java Technology ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Web Services implemented using JAX-WS (SOAP) or JAX-RS (RESTful) implementations use [JAXB (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) for the binding layer.  When using JAXB you can leverage the `@XmlTransient` annotation to exclude a field/property from the XML representation.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/jaxb-and-unmapped-properties.html

Answer (score 3):

In java properties which shouldnt be serialized are marked as transient or you can implement `Externalizable` interface instead of `Serializable` and ignore fields which you don't want to be serialized in your `readObject` and `writeObject` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but unfortunately the keyword transient can be applied only to class or instance variables with in a class , but i want it with in my webs service method .